# UIButton is not able to be centred on all devices in UITableViewCell - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have created a custom UITableViewCell which is added programatically in my view controller. The custom cell contains a button. The problem is that I cannot achieve the button being centred on all devices. If it's the 5s simulator, and I use self.frame.width for the x coordinate of the button frame, then it is centred - but not on the 6 or 6s, but if I use super.frame.width for the x-coord, it is then centred on the 6 simulator. Does anyone know how I can get it to be centered on all device screens? Here is the code for my custom button, and I simply return it as a UITableViewCell in the tableView delegate in my viewcontroller...

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public class ButtonCell: UITableViewCell {

    //Custom button to be added to the last cell to submit
    let buttonImage = UIImage(named: "add_pub_button") as UIImage?
    let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton

    /**
     Creates the ButtonCell

     - parameter style:           A constant indicating a cell style. See UITableViewCellStyle for descriptions of these constants.
     - parameter reuseIdentifier: A string used to identify the cell object if it is to be reused for drawing multiple rows of a table view. Pass nil if the cell object is not to be reused. You should use the same reuse identifier for all cells of the same form.

     - returns: An initialized TextInputCell object or nil if the object could not be created.
     */
    override public init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {

        //Overhangs the view slightly to avoid invalid constraints.
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.backgroundView = nil
        self.backgroundColor = nil
        self.tintColor = nil
        self.selectionStyle = .None

        button.frame = CGRectMake((self.frame.width - 134)/2, 0, 134, 44)
        button.tintColor = nil
        button.backgroundColor = nil
        button.setImage(buttonImage, forState: .Normal)

        self.contentView.addSubview(button)
    }

    /**
     Needed for initialization from a storyboard.
     - parameter aDecoder: An unarchiver object.
     - returns: An initialized ButtonCell object or nil if the object could not be created.
     */
    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not add the button to a second prototype cell in Storyboard, and use Auto Layout to center it?

Comment: I have many cells with have custom things like expanding datepickers/regular pickers/textfields...Is it possible to add a prototype cell that appears at the buttom of the tableView below the others as that is where the button is.

Comment: Of course.  Each prototype cell has an identifier. You simply dequeue a button storyboard cell for the row that should display the button.  It will save you from having to write or maintain that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set the frame related operation in `layoutSubviews` method

for example,

```
    private func setup() {

    //Overhangs the view slightly to avoid invalid constraints.
    self.clipsToBounds = true
    self.backgroundView = nil
    self.backgroundColor = nil
    self.tintColor = nil
    self.selectionStyle = .None

    //no need of setting the frame of button hear 
    //at the time initialisation there is no frame available for cell
    //button.frame = CGRectMake((self.frame.width - 134)/2, 0, 134, 44) 
    button.tintColor = nil
    button.backgroundColor = nil
    button.setImage(buttonImage, forState: .Normal)

    self.contentView.addSubview(button)
}

//set it hear because frame of the cell available hear
 override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    button.frame = CGRectMake((self.frame.width - 134)/2, 0, 134, 44)
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working, I'm trying it on other simulator devices to test and will update as correct when verified. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the frame. I would use [constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html). You can easily create a constraint that horizontally centers this by using the following:

```
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let centerX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
self.addConstraint(centerX)
```

Comment: I tried to add this in the setup() of the ButtonCell, but it's causing the app to crash as "The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint"

Comment: Its because you cannot add a constraint to a view that is not in the view hierarchy and when this cell gets initialized, its not in the view hierarchy. I would set up these constraints in storyboard or add them in programmatically in the table view data source